# integer overflow in constant expression

Tags: c, avr-gcc

While this compiles fine on Linux 64 bit with gcc:

```
#define CONST_1 255
#define CONST_2 255

#define CONST_PROD ((CONST_1) * (CONST_2))
```

it gives an overflow warning on avr-gcc (8 bit):

```
constants.c:13:31: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
 #define CONST_PROD ((CONST_1) * (CONST_2))
                               ^
```

which is fair enough since the result is too large for a 16 bit signed integer.

The warning goes away when defining the constant(s) like this:

```
#define CONST_1 255U
```

or by adding a cast:

```
#define CONST_PROD ((uint16_t)(CONST_1) * (CONST_2))
```

I think in effect both do the same but is one way preferred over the other?

Comment: `255U` or `255UL` is certainly the simplest solution. I guess you should review whether you use the constants in any context where signed behaviour is expected

Comment: Read about the **guaranteed** ranges of integers types. Signed integer overflow is always _undefined behaviour_ (aka "great trouble" or "disaster"). You are lucky the compiler caught it for constants. It will likely not when using variables, so be very careful! And you should avoid casts where possible.

Comment: Also, please consider using the standard [`<limits.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) include file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid casting, which can unexpectedly *narrow* the value.

Alternatives - best depends on many things.  In general, if the number is meant to be unsigned, append a `u` or use some `UINTN_C()`

```
 // u or U the same
 #define CONST_1 255U
 #define CONST_1 255u

 // 1u* to bring about unsigned math.  () around `CONST_1` shouldn't be necessary.
 #define CONST_PROD (1u*CONST_1 * CONST_2)

 // Macros for minimum-width integer constants
 #include <stdint.h>
 // UINT16_C() makes the constant type uint_least16_t
 #define CONST_PROD (UINT16_C(CONST_1) * UINT16_C(CONST_2))
```

OTOH, if a value is meant to be exact N bits and no other width,

```
 #define CONST16_MASK_MIDDLE_BITS  ((uint16_t) 0x00FFFF00u)
```

I see little value with `UL`.  If you want the constant to be a wide type, go for widest.

```
 #define CONST_1 255ULL
 // or 
 #define CONST_1 ((uintmax_t)255u)
```